# How to retrieve image from SharePoint list column using react js?

Tags: reactjs, image, sharepoint, spfx

I have given the code as:

```
<div classname=""><img src={"siteurl"}></div>
```

It is retrieving the specific image which i give in the url.

For example: I have 3 items in pages list,in which each item have images.I would like to retrieve all the items with values and display it in a table.I am able to display Title,Modified field in table but not the image.

I tried to get the image property by doing F12 and tried implementing that but getting the error as: 
Error - typescript - src\webparts\newsAppPart\components\NewsAppPart.
tsx(76,82): error TS2339: Property 'Url' does not exist on type '""'.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I got solution:                                                                                                                               <div classname=""><img src={item.columnname["Url"]}></div>                                                      columnname of which it have images.